# How do I programatically find location of source and test files in the source of a Python package?

Tags: python, pip

I have a project that depends on various Python packages (in the Pip sense, not the `import` sense) that are developed in parallel with the project. I normally have the additional Python packages in subdirectories (often, but not always, Git submodules), and install them with `pip install --editable`. I can then edit the source code in those packages along with the code in my top-level project, and commit the dependencies and then my own project.

I would like my top-level test script, which runs pytest against the code in my project, to be able to discover and run pytest and other tests in the dependent packages as well. Where the source and (possibly separate) tests are is usually defined in a `pyproject.toml` or `setup.py` in the dependent package, but this can be done in a myriad of ways.

Clearly pip and pytest understand how to find this sort of information when pointed at a directory containing the source for a Python package. How can  my own test scripts also get this information?